# Unimplementing Methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, exec

I want to unimplement methods **neg**() and **index**() in class iFuzzBool, but when I create an instance, '-' perfectly prints the negative value.  What am I doing wrong?

```
class iFuzzBool(float):

    def __new__(cls, value=0.0):
         return super().__new__(cls, value if 0.0 <= value <=1.0 else 0.0)

    for name, operator in (("__neg__","-"), ("__index__", "index()")):
        message = ("bad operand type for unary {0}: '{{self}}'".format(operator))

    exec("def {0}(self): raise TyperError(\"{1}\".format(self=self.__class__.__name__))".format(name, message))

    def __invert__(self):
        return iFuzzBool(1.0 - float(self))

    def __and__(self, other):
        return iFuzzBool(min(self, other))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({super().__repr__()})"



me_fuzz = iFuzzBool(.234)
print(-me_fuzz)
```

The expected result should raise a TypeError

Comment: Why use exec there?

Comment: so I don't have to manually unimplement each method, assuming I have over 30 methods to unimplement.

Comment: from the 2-tuple on the right of 'in'

Comment: This works for me if you indent the exec call into the for-loop body and remove the typo in the type error: `TyperError` -> `TypeError`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Awesome! Thanks for catching it. I didn't even notice. How do I like / accept your comment?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to inherit from float and then remove methods.  Define a class that does what you want, which has a float as an attribute.

Comment: This should be a comment IMO

Comment: I understand your option is the most pythonic, but supposing I wanted to inherit float then unimplement __neg__() and __index__() ?

Comment: There are good reasons not to inherit from float.  The methods you inherit will produce floats, not your type.  You mentioned having to unimplement 30 methods.  What are you keeping?

Comment: @NedBatchelder hypothetically, if I were to unimplement 30 methods from a type. And yes the output, ultimately, will be floats, although type(me_fuzz) shows iFuzzBool. I will be unimplementing << and other bitwise operators. My concern is if I were to be faced with the situation where there was a class that had  a lot of attributes I wanted (hence me implementing float) and a lot of attributes I don't want( hence the unimplementation) , how do I unimplement them fast rather than having to reimplement them and have a raise TypeError() in the function suite

Comment: It will be much easier to write the code you want with an encapsulated float than to try to whittle down a class inherited from float.  Sorry, I don't know how to do it the way you want.

Comment: Another option: leave the methods alone, and simply don't call them.